# Ubuntu 13.10 has no Suspend or Hibernate Options

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

I have a Lenova Yoga 2 Pro, and I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed.

I am having some issues setting the power functions. At the moment I can not suspend or hibernate the laptop.

So from Gnome 3.10 I have the option to Log Out, Shutdown & Restart. No option for Suspend / Hibernate.

However I can use these commands to get the right behaviour

```
sudo pm-suspend
sudo pm-hibernate
```

So the laptop knows how to do this, it just is not giving me the option and also when I set "Close screen lid" to suspend, well nothing happens. It feels like there is a "connection" not being made.

Comment: Do you see a battery status? If not, two things come to mind... First, the kernel may be blacklisting the fuel-gauge driver. Second, the BIOS/UEFI may be misreporting the chasis type. You can use `dmidecode` to see what the BIOS/UEFI is reporting. For an issue report that witnesses both issues, see [Bug 1690852, 5 to 20 minutes shutdowns on Cherry Trail machine](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1690852). The 1690852 was the reverse of your issue - it was a minipc acting like a tablet. You seem to be going the other way - a laptop acting like a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and is what you get when you don't stick with the stable version.

Open your command line and put this to edit the config file:

> sudo gedit
>   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla

Copy and paste below lines into the file and save it.

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

After reboot, the login screen session menu should have a Hibernate option.

If the first command does not work try this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Here is the question answered: https://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/hibernation-is-still-missing-from-menu-in-13-10-after-enabling-via-polkit-how-t

**Try also this:**

to enable the hibernate menu option all what you need to do is add “killall indicator-session-service”, without “”, to the stratup applications. and all is done automaticly evey time you start Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you - I have done this but still nothing, its really odd!

Comment: This is a bug and it might get fixed with future updates.